# Android Recycleview Multiple ViewTypes not working in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I have an app which uses Room Database to show data in recycleview. It works fine when i load data seperately from different tables. But i want to show data from both tables in a single recycleview with multiple viewtypes, i know how to combine tables in room but it's not working. I get empty cards in recycleview when i load the data. Here is what i have tried so far.
My Adapter Class

```
class CategoriesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

companion object {
    private const val TYPE_CATEGORIES = 0
    private const val TYPE_ARTICLES = 1
}

private val items: MutableList<Any> by lazy {
    ArrayList<Any>()
}

fun setItems(list: List<Any>) {
    items.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}


override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if (items[position] is Categories) TYPE_CATEGORIES  else TYPE_ARTICLES
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        TYPE_CATEGORIES -> CategoriesViewHolder.create(viewGroup)
        else -> ArticlesViewHolder.create(viewGroup)
    }
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when (holder) {
        is CategoriesViewHolder -> {
            if (items[position] is Categories)
                holder.bind(items[position] as Categories)
        }
        is ArticlesViewHolder -> {
            if (items[position] is Articles)
                holder.bind(items[position] as Articles)
        }
    }
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

}

class CategoriesViewHolder (parent: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(parent) {

val textView: TextView = parent.findViewById(R.id.categories_textView)

fun bind(category: Categories) {
    textView.text = category.categoryName



 }

companion object {
    fun create(parent: ViewGroup): CategoriesViewHolder {
        return CategoriesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.categories_item_layout, parent, false))
    }
}
}

class ArticlesViewHolder (parent: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(parent) {

val textView: TextView = parent.findViewById(R.id.titleText)

fun bind(articles : Articles) {
    textView.text = articles.articleName

}

companion object {
    fun create(parent: ViewGroup): ArticlesViewHolder {
        return ArticlesViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.article_item_layout, parent, false))
    }
}
}
```

this is how i set data from my activity

```
 val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext)
    dao = db.articleDao()

    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.categories_recycle_view)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = CategoriesAdapter()
    adapter.setItems(dao.getAllArticlesAndCategories())
```

Can anyone help.
P.s i'm new to kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 adapter.setItems(dao.getAllArticlesAndCategories())
```

Use live data observer to avoid processing on main thread and debug in observe function of live data to confirm you are receiving correct data from DB.

Comment: According to the scenario that you recommend, there are 2 scenarios. Could you add a "No" checkbox and then make it visible, in the questions that will be needed?

Answer (score -1):

calling code one line of code is missing

val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext)
dao = db.articleDao()

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.categories_recycle_view)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView.adapter = CategoriesAdapter()
adapter.setItems(dao.getAllArticlesAndCategories())
```

it should be:

val db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext)
dao = db.articleDao()

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.categories_recycle_view)
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

adapter=CategoriesAdapter()

 adapter.setItems(dao.getAllArticlesAndCategories())
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

I would like to thank for the question and the code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, I corrected my answer